# Nlog does not delete the log file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, logging, nlog

I am creating an application ASP MVC.  I use for NLOG this configuration file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<target name="file"
        xsi:type="File"
        layout="${date}|${level}|${message}"
        fileName="C:\Log\log.txt"
        createDirs="true"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        concurrentWrites="true"
        archiveFileName="CopyLogs\${LogFileName}.{#####}.${LogFileExtension}"
        archiveAboveSize="500000" maxArchiveFiles="200"
        archiveNumbering="Rolling"
        deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"
 />

 </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

When log file size is equal to archiveAboveSize - logging stops. When I delete an existing file a new log file is created and written.  How do I properly create a configuration file  for NLOG?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target)

### Size-based file archival

Log files can be automatically archived by moving them to another location after reaching certain size. The following configuration will create logs/logfile.txt which will be archived to archives/log.000000.txt', archives/log.000001.txt', archives/log.000002.txt' and so on once the main log file reaches 10KB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#####}.txt"
            archiveAboveSize="10240"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="iso-8859-2" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```